# Can a choice be subconscious?

Tags: meaning

Today, some friends and I were having a discussion about "nature vs. nurture", specifically with regard to whether or not people choose to be gay. One friend suggested that he believes it's more "nurture" rather than "nature", i.e. that maybe some event occurred in a person's early childhood that caused them to tend towards homosexuality, as opposed to their homosexuality being inherent in their DNA.

It seems to me that in either case, it's not the person's *choice*. He responded by saying, "Yes, it is a choice--it's a *subconscious* choice."

The Oxford English dictionary defines '[choice](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/choice)' as "An act of choosing between two or more possibilities", and it defines to '[choose](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/choose)' as to "Pick out (someone or something) as being the best or most appropriate of two or more alternatives". This tells me that there's no such thing as a *subconscious choice*, and so, if my friend's belief is true, people still don't *choose* to be gay.

Am I correct? Or is there such a thing as a "subconscious choice"?

Comment: Just so you know, there is [philosophy.se] Stack Exchange for this.

Comment: When your body chooses to breathe in, is that a conscious choice?

Comment: Reflexes are subconscious choices, I believe.

Comment: @NVZ I'm more concerned about the definition of the word, and about whether or not there exists a better word to convey what he was trying to convey

Comment: Any reason for the down-vote?

Comment: Can you imagine how the phrase "subconscious choice" could make sense to your friend? The meaning of a word is not derived from dictionary entries; dictionary entries are derived from the way words are used. If enough people like your friend use the word "choice" this way, it's misguided to tell him that he's "incorrect" because the dictionary doesn't explain this use of the word.

Comment: @villapx not my vote, but probably because someone thought that this question is too deep.

Comment: Like fingerprints and handedness, sexual orientation seems to be one of the things determined not primarily by DNA, but by the process of prenatal development.

Comment: @Jim, I wouldn't think that's a choice at all, because I'm not deciding to do it...my body just _does_ it. I could choose to modify my breathing, or choose to hold my breath, but I wouldn't call my everyday breathing a choice

Comment: @villapx Which is exactly why I said this is not a question about language. It's probably suited to [biology.se] or [philosophy.se], maybe.

Comment: @NVZ I'm not asking whether or not people are born gay, I'm asking if it makes any sense to call something that's subconscious a "choice". Does that help?

Comment: @NVZ: I still *might* downvote (I've just *closevoted* as POB), but that certainly wouldn't be because I think the question is "too deep". I just think it's Off Topic for sure (hence closevote), but if I were to decide it's essentially a "peeve" that would be my reason for downvoting.

Comment: ...[researchers using brain scanners could predict people's decisions seven seconds before the test subjects were even aware of making them](https://www.wired.com/2008/04/mind-decision/)

Comment: @villapx It sounds a lot like ["Unconscious thought theory"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconscious_thought_theory), which is **psychology**, not English usage. I'm not sure what type of answer you expect; you should clarify that.

Comment: @Laurel Aha! Then this might be better answered in [cogsci.se]

Comment: The term "unconscious" or "subconscious choice" is certainly used. Generally it means a choice made by the person that they are not conscious of making. For example in the paper title "The Conscious Decision versus the Unconscious Choice: Observed Grocery Shopping" ([link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241042738_The_Conscious_Decision_versus_the_Unconscious_Choice_Observed_Grocery_Shopping)).

Comment: @MetaEd that answers my question. Perhaps I should rephrase it to better get across what I'm asking, but you hit the nail on the head.

Comment: The conscious mind chooses between options. Does the subconscious mind also choose between options?  It may not, it may simply run preset programmes of action such as breathing, driving a car (once the technique has been embedded), falling in love.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't really a question about word usage, but about the topics of free will and cognitive science that can't be effectively adjudicated here.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to answer this question without straying too far into medical science, philosophy, or dictionary definitions is complicated. I think it might be easier to use terms a little less associated with psychology, specifically psychoanalytic Drive Theory.

For conscious decisions, I'll call this **free will**. And for "subconscious choice" I'll use **underlying cause (or decision)**. Whether these are fair synonyms is certainly open to debate, but I feel they minimize confounders as above. A term frequently used with homosexuality is *latent*. I won't use that either.

An example above was *breathing.* Breathing is involuntary, it happens whether we want it to or not, but we can use our free will to alter the rate, volume, and mouth v. nasal. Involuntary actions and reflexes are related to genetics, and I don't believe them to be synonymous with *subconscious*.

You asked, *Can a choice be subconscious?*

Let's use a classic example of the husband having had a bad day at work, comes home, and kicks the dog for a minor slight. His wife asks, Why did you do that?" The guy says, "I wasn't really thinking about it. It just happened. I hope I never do that again."

So even if claims he wasn't using free will in his decision, the underlying cause is obvious. The man is still culpable for his decision (without getting into legal logistics). In order for him to promote a kick-free lifestyle, he needs to do something prior to coming home to arrive with less aggression OR his wife can keep the dog in a separate room.

In this regard, there is still a choice. One would hope the man develops the free will to avoid kicking the dog even under the most stressful of times. However, by being proactive, even an underlying decision can develop the nature of free will by altering the variables responsible for the action.

With regards to homosexuality, there are some clearly making free will choices, such as bisexuals and the transgendered (obviously some will disagree with me but whatever), and there are those who have never found a member of the opposite sex attractive in their life.

In the latter, I find the underlying cause, the "subconscious choice," to be unknown. The free will choice is whether or not to engage in sexual relations.

**To answer your question, yes, there are subconscious choices, but they must be separated from reflexes or involuntary actions.** If a man has never found a woman attractive, how can his homosexuality be a choice on any level? If a man comes home and kicks his dog, there are things that can be done to promote a different action.

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat a question of semantics.  Choice has a number of [meanings](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/choice?).

***Selection***: an act or instance of choosing.  Under this definition, even if you argue "nature", that qualifies as a choice.  Any selection the person makes, or their body makes for them, could be called a choice.

A number of other definitions include or imply a cognitive process:

***Option***: the right, power, or opportunity to choose

***Preference***: something that is preferred or preferable to others

***Selection based on thought***: a carefully selected supply, e.g., 
This restaurant has a fine choice of wines.

So you can choose a definition to support either case.  If you choose simple selection, it can be subconscious.  If you choose a definition based on thinking, it can only be conscious.  Beyond that, you're getting into the realm of medicine or philosophy and this is really the wrong site to tackle that question.